# MySQL Group By 2 adjacent Dates

Tags: mysql

I have one table named viewlist as follows

```
     Id            article_id           viewdate
 --------------------------------------------------
     1                1                2015-07-01
     2                1                2015-07-01
     3                1                2015-07-01
     4                2                2015-07-01
     5                2                2015-07-01
     6                1                2015-07-02
     7                2                2015-07-02
     8                1                2015-07-03
     9                2                2015-07-03
    10                1                2015-07-05
    11                1                2015-07-05
 ----------------------------------------------------
```

i need to write a MySQL query to get count and article_id by grouping adjacent viewdate field

wanted result as follows

```
 article_id            count                   date_period
-----------------------------------------------------------------
     1                   4                2015-07-01 - 2015-07-02
     2                   3                2015-07-01 - 2015-07-02
     1                   1                2015-07-03 - 2015-07-04
     2                   1                2015-07-03 - 2015-07-04
     1                   2                2015-07-05 - 2015-07-06
```

Is there any simple query to get this type of result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use something on these lines

```
SELECT v.article_id, COUNT(*), CONCAT(b.dt, ' - ', b.dt2) as 'date_period'
FROM viewlist v INNER JOIN
    (SELECT a.dt, DATE_ADD(a.dt, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS dt2 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(viewdate) AS dt FROM viewlist WHERE (DAY(viewdate) MOD 2) = 1) a) b ON v.viewdate BETWEEN b.dt AND b.dt2
GROUP BY 1, 3
ORDER BY b.dt
```

Comment: is it possible to group adjacent 2 date rows, 
ie  group by combining 2015-07-01 and 2015-07-02, 
2015-07-03 and 2015-07-05

Comment: you can use one interval, either one day or two days or three or..., as long as you dont want to change the query every time the data changes. To change the interval, just change INTERVAL 1 DAY to INTERVAL 2 DAY or INTERVAL 3 DAY... and its DAY not DAYS